# How do I add an AJAX notification instead of addError() in Magento?

Tags: ajax, magento, magento-1.9

I've implemented a Max Order Value restriction on my Magento Store from this tutorial: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-maximum-allowed-order-amount/

The notification uses the following to show the error message:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError(
            $this->_helper->__($this->_helper->getSingleOrderTopAmountMsg(), $formattedPrice));
```

Unfortunately, this is only shown on the next page load since it's Session based.

However, I would like the message as a popup when 'Add to cart' button is clicked. This could be a simple javascript alert or ideally a nicely styled popup.

I've looked into Ajax using:

```
$response = array();       
$response['message'] = 'Your cart exceeds the maximum allowed order value';

$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
```

but I'm not entirely sure how to get the response on the front end via jQuery.

Any help would be appreciate :)

Cheers